# Angular UI Bootstrap $uibModal not being injected?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use angular-bootstrap and for some reason I'm getting an **unknown provider** error.

Everything looks to be in order. I've bower installed the latest version, as you can see in my bower.json file below.

Here is my bower.json file:

```
 {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.8",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.3.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "angular-xeditable": "^0.2.0",
    "oclazyload": "^1.0.9",
    "angular-motion": "^0.4.4",
    "angular-local-storage": "^0.5.0",
    "angular-sweetalert": "latest",
    "angular-password": "^1.0.3",
    "ng-file-upload-shim": "^12.2.12",
    "ng-file-upload": "^12.2.12",
    "ng-img-crop": "ngImgCrop#^0.3.2",
    "ngvideo": "^1.0.2",
    "angular-bootstrap": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "clientApp",
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.x"
  }
}
```

I've added the reference to my model:

```
angular
  .module('clientApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ui.router',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'oitozero.ngSweetAlert'
  ])
```

And I'm injecting it into my controller:

```
.controller('BalanceWheelController', function($scope, $uibModal, lessons, $state) {
```

And my function to call the modal is:

```
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false,
            templateUrl: 'questionsModal.html',
            controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance, SweetAlert) {

                $scope.close = function() {
                    //self.showingExpenses = false;
                    $uibModalInstance.close();
                    videoId.play();
                };
            }
        });
```

So I'm really confused as to why I'm getting the following error:

```
angular.js:10160 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $uibModal
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.32/$injector/unpr?p0=%24templateRequestProvider%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24uibModal
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3803:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3931:39)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3808:45
    at getService (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3931:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3958:13)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3809:37
    at getService (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3931:39)
    at invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3958:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3978:23) <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Here are my js references in the index.html:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sweetalert/SweetAlert.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-password/angular-password.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ng-file-upload-shim/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ng-img-crop/compile/minified/ng-img-crop.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: its looks like you missed to add reference for ui-bootstrap.js?

Comment: @NikhilVM maybe just the wrong `.js` file as `$uibModal` is present but `$templateRequest` is not

Comment: @NikhilVM Not sure what you mean. It is referenced between 'ngTouch',
   ( 'ui.bootstrap',)  'oitozero.ngSweetAlert'

Comment: @cnak2, I meant to add  ui-bootstrap.js in index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've managed to install Angular 1.2.32 (note the version in the error URL) which does not have a `$templateRequest` provider. This has happened via one (or more) of your dependencies.

Change your `resolutions` to match your `angular` dependency version.

```
"resolutions": {
    "angular": "^1.5.8"
}
```

While you're there, I suggest you match the versions of all Angular dependencies to be **exactly** the same, ie `angular-animate`, `angular-mocks`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Phil. That did the trick!  Thank you to everyone for the assist.